# replacing horizontal rules in casual-style of moderncv with vertical

Tags: moderncv

I have the following MWE using `moderncv`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


\name{Test}{Testing}
\title{Test title}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{0000--9999}{asd}{asd}{asd}{}{\emph{asd}.
}


\section{Education}
\cventry{0000--9999}{asd}{asd}{asd}{}{\emph{asd}.
}


\end{document}
```

There are two things I would like to play around with and try alter:

1. The name `Test Testing` appears in the upper right corner, where the first name `Test` appears in grey and the last name `Testing` appears in black. I would like for both to be black, where am I able to change these colors?
2. With this style, horizontal bars appear above the years  `0000-9999` between each entry. Is it possible to make these bars vertical instead and appear between the year and the entry? Exactly similar to if I had used `fancy` instead of `casual`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the first name to black it is probably simplest to patch the command `\makecvhead`

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@firstname}{}{}
\makeatother
```

You can combine the body definition of `fancy` with `casual`.

```
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvbody{5}
```

Comment: I tried with `\textcolor{black}{Test}`, that also worked well for changing the color

Comment: You are right. But this will change the text color of every appearance of the first name and not only the one in the header. I think patching is a cleaner solution.